# Excel changing the row reference in a formula

Tags: worksheet-function

I have the formula "=k6+h7" in the cell K7,  I would like to have excel calculate the new cell number when I delete a row.  The formula is populated in all the K column cells.

Comment: One method, if I understand you correctly, is to convert your sheet to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Owh.. Instead if using the cell address (k6,h6) as the reference.. you can 'generate' the address using `indirect()` and `row()` .

In the K7 cell , `=row()` will results in 7 . So :

```
=k6+h7
```

can be replaced by :

```
=indirect("k"&(row()-1))+indirect("h"&(row()))
```

When a row is deleted, the `row()` values follows.

Hope it helps.